# SSIS - what is being processed right now?

Tags: sql-server, logging, ssis

For a report, I need to know what sub-components (parts of the control flow) of a SSIS package are being processed right now. I know about the catalog view `catalog.executable_statistics`, but it seems a record is added there *after* the execution of a given execution path is finished.

Is there a way to check what execution paths already entered pre-execute phase and not yet entered the post-execute phase? In other words, what is the package working on right now?

We use SQL server 2016 Enterprise edition.

Edit:
I prefer a solution that would work with the default logging level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is querying `catalog.execution_component_phases` which will display the most recently run execution phase of each sub-component within a Data Flow Task while the package is executing.  This will let you see what component has started a phase such as `PreExecute` but hasn't yet begun a subsequent one like `PostExecute` or `ReleaseConnections`.  To use this, you'll need to set the logging level at either Performance or Verbose as well.

Comment: This looks good, thanks for answer! I had no idea about this. I would prefer a solution without raising the logging level though. The `catalog.executable_statistics` is being filled even with the default logging level (problem is the record is written after the task finishes). Any ideas?

Comment: On the Catalog Properties for SSISDB, set Clean Logs Periodically to True, the Retention Period to the number of days that you want to have records for, and then the SSIS Server Maintenance job will clean rows older than the specified number of days next time it runs from this DMV as well as others in SSISDB.  This job can lead to blocking issues, so I'd recommend executing it at a time when there isn't much activity, possibly on a customized schedule using the msdb.dbo.sp_start_job stored procedure.

Comment: I probably did not express myself clearly, sorry for my English. By "being filled" i meant that records are being added (but AFTER the execution of the given path finishes). I did not mean it is filled up.

Comment: In other words: Is there a way (with default logging level) to check what execution paths are being processed right now? (without any custom SQL tasks and similar solutions requiring changes of all the packages). Thanks!

Comment: The default logging level won't need to be changed at the catalog level on SSISDB and can remain at basic or none.  The logging can be done on a just specific package, or even a particular execution of it.  Sorry, I was thinking you were looking for a larger scope.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't any logging out of the box that will tell you the exact state of all subcomponents in the package when executing it from SQL server.

I simply use an SQL task at the start of some steps that inserts, and when done, updates a row with specifics like start/end datetime, package name & amount of rows processed. You could add a column which specifies the subcomponents affected is this way.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I used this technique too. But now I face tens of packages not written by me, and my goal is to provide a report showing exact "stage" of any running package. Adding these SQL tasks to all of the packages would be cumbersome.